# JSTL export number as text to excel

Tags: java, excel, struts, jstl, el

Hello I'm currently exporting a list of Strings to Excel with JSTL

I'm cycling trough the list of values to export, and even if 
the values are defined as String when I have something like "001" 
on my excel page I get "1" the same list contains values like "XXX"
therefore I thought excel would be smart enough to know that I have
a list of strings and not numbers.

My first workaround was to add a trailing space to every value but 
that's not such an elegant solution.

What is the best way to tell excel that my List is made of Strings
and export the values as in the list ?

Here is a sample of what I'm currently doing :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a viable solution, actually it is possible to format excel cells
via CSS, in my case it was enough to add an CSS class with the following format 
to the interested TD

```
<style type="text/css">
    .excel_data_value_string{   
    mso-number-format:"\@";
}
</style>

<c:forEach var="object" items="${objectList}">
    <td class="excel_data_value_string">
        <c:out value="${object.value}"/>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Which specifies that the column should be treated as String, for those interested there
are many other ways to format the output :

Styling Excel cells with mso-number-format

```
mso-number-format:"0"                       //NO Decimals
mso-number-format:"0\.000"                  //3 Decimals
mso-number-format:"\#\,\#\#0\.000"          //Comma with 3 dec
mso-number-format:"mm\/dd\/yy"              //Date7
mso-number-format:"mmmm\ d\,\ yyyy"         //Date9
mso-number-format:"m\/d\/yy\ h\:mm\ AM\/PM" //D -T AMPM
mso-number-format:"Short Date"              //01/03/1998
mso-number-format:"Medium Date"             //01-mar-98
mso-number-format:"d\-mmm\-yyyy"            //01-mar-1998
mso-number-format:"Short Time"              //5:16
mso-number-format:"Medium Time"             //5:16 am
mso-number-format:"Long Time"               //5:16:21:00
mso-number-format:"Percent"                 //Percent - two decimals
mso-number-format:"0%"                      //Percent - no decimals
mso-number-format:"0\.E+00"                 //Scientific Notation
mso-number-format:"\@"                      //Text
mso-number-format:"\#\ ???\/???"            //Fractions - up to 3 digits (312/943)
mso-number-format:"\0022£\0022\#\,\#\#0\.00"    //£12.76
mso-number-format:"\#\,\#\#0\.00_ \;\[Red\]\-\#\,\#\#0\.00\ "   //2 decimals, negative numbers in red and signed (1.56 -1.56)
```